# tastypie obj_create and authorization

Tags: python, django, authorization, tastypie

I use `tastypie 0.12.2-dev` to create API for my `django` site. I wrote a class authorization (ApprovedLaptopsAuthorization) and used it in my ModelResource (RecordResource) class. The endpoint of `RecordResource` is http://myserver/book/api/record.

HTTP GET Request to that endpoint is working correctly. (permissions are checked in read_list() method of ApprovedLaptopsAuthorization class). Now I try to check HTTP POST Request by sending correct JSON data. The problem is that any of ApprovedLaptopsAuthorization methods (create_list(), create_detail()) does not running during that operation. As a result, I can not restrict access to create object  operation and any user can create object in any time. Where the mistake in my code?

```
class ApprovedLaptopsAuthorization(Authorization):
    """
    Авторизация путем проверки наличия разрешения на использоание планшета, с которого осуществляется запрос
    """

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        if not bundle.request.user.laptop.approved:
            raise Unauthorized(u"Доступ планшета к данным не подтвержден администратором.")
        return object_list

    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        if not bundle.request.user.laptop.approved:
            raise Unauthorized(u"Доступ планшета к данным не подтвержден администратором.")
        return True

    def create_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        print "create list"
        if not bundle.request.user.laptop.approved:
            raise Unauthorized(u"Доступ планшета к данным не подтвержден администратором.")
        return object_list

    def create_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        print "create detail"
        raise BadRequest(u"Выполнение данной операции запрещено.")

    def update_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise BadRequest(u"Выполнение данной операции запрещено.")

    def update_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise BadRequest(u"Выполнение данной операции запрещено.")

    def delete_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise BadRequest(u"Выполнение данной операции запрещено.")

    def delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise BadRequest(u"Выполнение данной операции запрещено.")    


class RecordResource(ModelResource):
    """
    Точка доступа к записям
    """

    pages = ToManyField(PageResource, 'pages', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Record.objects.all()
        limit = 0
        max_limit = 0
        resource_name = 'record'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = []
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = ApprovedLaptopsAuthorization()
        serializer = CommonSerializer(formats=['json'])
        always_return_data = True

    def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
        return {}

    @staticmethod
    def unauthorized_result(exception):
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(
            response=HttpUnauthorized(
                json.dumps({'error': exception.message}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
            )
        )

    def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        """
        :param bundle: tastypie bundle
        :param kwargs: tastypie params
        :return: Возвращает список записей и страниц на них
        """
        bundle.request.user.laptop.ip = ip_from_bundle(bundle)
        bundle.request.user.laptop.save()
        return super(RecordResource, self).obj_get_list(bundle, **kwargs)

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        """
        :param bundle: tastypie bundle
        :param kwargs: tastypie params
        :return: Создает запись и страницы на основе переданного JSON-а
        """
        bundle.request.user.laptop.ip = ip_from_bundle(bundle)
        bundle.request.user.laptop.save()

        records = bundle.data.get('records', '')
        if not records:
            raise BadRequest(u"Поле записей для загрузки на сервер (records) не заполнено")
        for recidx, record in enumerate(records):
            pages = record.get('pages', '')
            if not pages:
                raise BadRequest(u"Поле страниц для загрузки на сервер (pages) не заполнено (запись {})".format(recidx))
            for pageidx, page in enumerate(pages):
                image = page.get('image', '')
                if not image:
                    BadRequest(u"Поле картинки для загрузки на сервер (image) не заполнено (запись {}, страница {})".
                               format(recidx, pageidx))

        for record in records:
            new_rec = Record.objects.create(author=BookConfiguration.get_solo().record_author_default +
                                            ' (' + timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + ')')
            new_rec.save()
            pages = record['pages']
            for page in pages:
                new_page = Page.objects.create(image=SimpleUploadedFile(page['image']['name'],
                                               base64.b64decode(page['image']['file']),
                                               page['image'].get('content_type',
                                               'application/octet-stream')), record=new_rec, updated=timezone.now())
                new_page.save()
        bundle.obj = new_rec
        return bundle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not received an answer to my question, and added these lines to the top of the method RecordResource.obj_create():

```
if not bundle.request.user.laptop.approved:
    raise Unauthorized(u"Доступ планшета к данным не подтвержден администратором.")
```